# Appending a list of dicts as an element of another list (Python)

Tags: python, list

I've two lists, where in 1 I store information of few celebrities, and another list where I store awards information pertaining to these actors.

The problem am trying to solve is to combine these 2 lists into one where the award information becomes an attribute which is essentially a list of awards. And yes this is simple to achieve.

```
for actor in actor_info:
    for award in award_list:
        if actor['personid'] == award['personid']:
            if not actor.get('awards', False):
                actor.update({'awards':[]})
            actor['awards'].append(award)
```

But if you observe the code above, it iterates `len(actor_info) * len(award_list)` times which is not an elegant solution. Is there any other perspective for this problem, where the execution cycles are much less.

---

***Note:***

To explain the problem much more clearly, I've described below the data structure am using. Each element in the actor_info and award_info list is essentially a dictionary.

```
actor_info = []

d = {}
d['personid'] = 1210
d['firstname'] = 'Robert , Jr'
d['lastname'] = 'Downey'
d['birthplace'] = 'manhattan, NY'

d1 = {}
d1['personid'] = 2842
d1['firstname'] = 'Brad'
d1['lastname'] = 'Pitt'
d1['birthplace'] = 'Shawnee, OK'

d2 = {}
d2['personid'] = 361
d2['fname'] = 'Cate'
d2['lname'] = 'Blanchett'
d2['birthplace'] = 'Melbournce, Victoria'

d3 = {}
d3['personid'] = 261
d3['fname'] = 'Meg'
d3['lname'] = 'Ryan'
d3['birthplace'] = 'Melbournce, Victoria'

actor_info.append(d)
actor_info.append(d1)
actor_info.append(d2)
actor_info.append(d3)
```

award information:

```
k = {} 
k['year'] = '1992'
k['won'] = 'NO'
k['category'] = 'Best Actor'
k['name'] = 'Academy Award'
k['movie'] = 'Chaplin'
k['personid'] = 1210

k1 = {}
k1['year'] = '2008'
k1['won'] = 'NO'
k1['category'] = 'Best Actor'
k1['name'] = 'Academy Award'
k1['movie'] = 'Tropic thunder'
k1['personid'] = 1210

k2 = {}
k2['year'] = '2008'
k2['won'] = 'NO'
k2['category'] = 'Best Actor'
k2['name'] = 'Academy Award'
k2['movie'] = 'The Curious Case of Benjamin Button'
k2['personid'] = 2842

k3 = {}
k3['year'] = '1989'
k3['won'] = 'yes'
k3['category'] = 'Best supporting Actress'
k3['name'] = 'Academy award'
k2['movie'] = 'Aviator'
k3['personid'] = 361

award_list = []
award_list.append(k)
award_list.append(k1)
award_list.append(k2)
award_list.append(k3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should switch from dictionaries to `collections.namedtuple`, which allows you to access the data as plain attributes.

Anyway, you can avoid the quadratic iteration by making a lookup table before hand.

```
idToActor = {a['personid']:a for a in actor_info}

for award in award_list:
    actor = idToActor[award['personid']]
    actor.setdefault('awards',[]).append(award)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of collections.namedtuple, will implement it now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would restructure how you store actor_info to something like this:

```
actor_info['personid'] = {'fname':'Cate',...,"awards":list()}
```

With your current code this could be achieve with the following code:

```
actor_info = {}
for actor in [d,d1,d2,d3]:
    actor_info[actor['personid']] = dict([(k,v) for (k,v) in actor.items() if k != 'personid'])
    actor_info[actor['personid']]['awards'] = list()
```

Now to give each actor their award(s)

```
for award in award_list:
    if actor_info.has_key(award['personid']): #if an actor exists with the same personID
        actor_info[award['personid']]['awards'].append(award) #append the award to their award list
```

This will run in approximately O(N) time.